# WKWebView notification when view is actually shown

Tags: swift, screenshot, ios9, wkwebview

I want to take a screenshot of a `WKWebView`. I call the method `drawViewHierarchyInRect` (with screen updates set to `true`) right after the web view finished loading - for this purpose I observe the `loading` property of the web view. However, I noticed, that at the time the web view notifies me that loading has finished, it doesn't actually display itself on the screen. That's why the screenshot is always only white. When I take the screenshot 0.5 seconds after loading (which is obviously too long) the screenshot shows the desired result. My problem is: I don't know when the web view actually displays itself on the screen, I could set the delay to 0.05 probably but I can't be a 100% sure it works every time. My question is therefore: How can I be notified when the web view is actually displayed an is ready for a screenshot.

Thanks in advance!

BTW: I'm using Swift 2.0 and iOS 9 with Xcode 7 (official release)

Answer (score 6):

as I've just worked on this, let me know what I tried and how I figured it out. I tried a couple of things, first, a WKUserScript

```
let webViewUserScript = WKUserScript(
        source: "window.onload = function() { webkit.messageHandlers.status.postMessage(\(wkwebView.hashValue)) }",
        injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd,
        forMainFrameOnly: true
    )
```

on the "status" namespace. This theoretically waits for all contents to be loaded, and then calls the WKScriptMessageHandler

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage){ }
```

when registered via

```
wkwebView.configuration.userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "status")
```

where I thought everything would be ready. Worked sometimes, but not always.

As you, I've also tried adding a WKNavigationDelegate and using

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) { }
```

Again, this didn't work. Also, adding an observer for the estimatedProgress value

```
wkwebView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress", options: .New, context: nil)
```

and then trying to make the screenshot within

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) { }
```

didn't work.

However, what does work is to check upon the webView's content size regularly. I've did this within the userContentController function, which is called by the WKUserScript - but you can also do this within the didFinishNavigation function, and then simply change the function which is to be called again. Here the code:

```
let _contentSize = webview.scrollView.contentSize;

if (_contentSize.height == 0){          
  dispatch_after(createDispatchTime(0.01), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.userContentController(userContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage: message)
  }
  return
}
```

This essentially checks on the contentSize height property and if it's zero, it will call the method again every 0.01 seconds until the property is set. Here are the functions I used for creating the screenshot

```
var view : UIView!

if self.useSnapShot {
   // Use the snapshot function
   view = webView.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)

} else {
   // Draw the view as UIImage
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webView.frame.size, false, 0.0)
   webView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(webView.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
   let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
   view = UIImageView(image: snapshot)
   view.frame = webView.frame
}
```

I've tested it on both device and simulator and it works.

**Edit**

Here the function for creating the dispatch time

```
private func createDispatchTime(seconds: Double) -> dispatch_time_t{
    let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    return dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
}
```

**Edit #2**

I created a gist which shows an even better way I believe
https://gist.github.com/christopherhelf/1640454bcace39a87c93#file-wkwebviewplus-swift

I replaced the setContentSize function of the webviews UIScrollview and notify the parent class that a change has been made.

Comment: I tried your swizzle method implementation. Even this too gets fired before webView actually renders for very fast web Pages like Wikipedia

Comment: You could also observe the contentSize property instead of firing off a delayed function or overwriting setContentSize.  This seems to work on detecting size changes, but it also seems to fire off on a regular animation cycle despite no change.

Comment: This one is definitely one of the best answers.
iOS WebView didFinishLoad is called when Main content is loaded, but iOS WebKit doesn't have any reliable controls for Javascript.
The problem stands here. Main content is loaded, but some javascript still working (loading, redirecting e.t.c) and WebKit doesn't get track of it.
The solution is to have controls on javascript web content and call script  message when all data is loaded.
I'm using [ https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge ] (WebViewJavascriptBridge) for that.

Comment: Now there is an `isLoading()` method which returnes a boolean which you can check instead of checking the contentsize height.

Comment: @peacer212 can find the when avplayer is show in WKWebView if any solution for this see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview