# Swift WKWebView: Can't find variable error when calling method

Tags: swift, swift3, wkwebview

I am trying to pass GPS coordinates to a method call `setIOSNativeAppLocation`. I have the following code below but I am getting this error:

```
A JavaScript exception occurred" 
UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=
ReferenceError:
Can't find variable: setIOSNativeAppLocation, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=
http://mywebsite.com, NSLocalizedDescription=
A JavaScript exception occurred, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=24})
```

I am not sure if it has something to do with the syntax or anything else. If someone knows what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

---

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {



   if(myCurrentLoc != nil){


      let lat = myCurrentLoc.coordinate.latitude
      let lon = myCurrentLoc.coordinate.longitude


      print(lat);
      print(lon);

      webView.evaluateJavaScript("setIOSNativeAppLocation(\(lat), \(lon));")  { (result, error) in
         guard error == nil else {
            print("there was an error")
            print(error)
            return
         }

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you managed to fix this?

Comment: @San It had to do with the fact that not all the javascript files were loaded at the time this method was called. I just used a local variable instead to store the lat and lon. You need to add an observer I think if you want to execute after loading. This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603010/detect-when-wkwebview-has-finished-loading-every-time

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had similar requirement like you to send some data from native to angular js web app. I managed to fix it by declaring global variable like what you said. 
var updateAccessKey = function (accessKey){
        
    console.log("Generated from the native app" + accessKey);
}

Answer (score 2):

I think this can help you out- The way we are passing parameter here.

we should put it in single quote(**'\(lat)', '\(lon)'**) else it will be like a variable.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) { 
if(myCurrentLoc != nil){


  let lat = myCurrentLoc.coordinate.latitude
  let lon = myCurrentLoc.coordinate.longitude


  print(lat);
  print(lon);

  webView.evaluateJavaScript("setIOSNativeAppLocation('\(lat)', '\(lon)');")  { (result, error) in
     guard error == nil else {
        print("there was an error")
        print(error)
        return
     }
   }

 }

}
```