# How to call JavaScript function with/without parameter in WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, swift3, wkwebview

I have loaded website url in **WKWebView**.
At some stage after handling **WKScriptMessageHandler**, I did some native operation.

After finish native operation I want to call a java script function in existing loaded **WKWebView**.

For testing Javascript function is simple

```
function try_once()
{
    // some code
}
```

And in Swift I did:

```
let str = "try_once();"

self.wkWeb.evaluateJavaScript(str, completionHandler: { (obj, error) in

                if error != nil
                {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Object : \(String(describing: obj))")
                }
            })
```

**But I got this error:**

> Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred"
>   UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1,
>   WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=ReferenceError: Can't find variable:
>   try_once,
>   WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=http://SOMEURL/user/signin/?_next=/v2/#,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred,
>   WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=9})

Answer (score 0):

It might be because javascript function you are trying to execute is not loaded at the time of method call. You can add an observer to execute it after loading of the script.
For adding observer look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37129148/3824808).

Reference: [Can't find variable error when calling method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39800227/3824808)

Answer (score 0):

try this method for with params:

```
let str = """
   try_once();"""
```

self.wkWeb.evaluateJavaScript(str, completionHandler: { (obj, error) in

```
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Object : \(String(describing: obj))")
            }
        })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answer updated as you need. trick is just add your desire function into """ ...""" this instead of "..."

Answer (score -2):

Add your java script function with HTML which you want to load and call that JavaScript function as below.

**For WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=ReferenceError: Can't find variable: try_once**

It should be in single quote(**'\(idValue)', '\(value)'**) else it will be like a variable.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) { 

 let idValue = some id value int                                             
 let value =   some value String

  webView.evaluateJavaScript("setResultValue('\(idValue)', '\(value)');", completionHandler: { (data, error) in
           if let err = error {
                    print(err)
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
              } else {
                  guard let dataValue = data else {return}
                  print(dataValue)            
            }
  })
}
```